# Return To Title Bar When The Lock Button Is Pressed Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a really simple 2 activity app, title screen and main game. I'm trying to make it so that when the user presses the lock button, the app will reappear in the title screen when they unlock the phone. The problem I'm having is that over half the time, I'm getting an exception in the title screen activity when I unlock the phone again. Here's what I've got so far, I know this is probably not the best way, but I was struggling a little. Here's what I'm doing in the main game activity

```
// On pause, return to main title page
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Create intent to go back to the title menu
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTitle.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And here's what's causing the error in the title bar

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_title_screen);

    // Make sure that the volume buttons change the media volume in the app
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    radioGroupSound = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupSound);
    radioGroupText = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupText);

    // Make the start text blink
    TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStart );
    Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    anim.setDuration(500); //You can manage the time of the blink with this parameter
    anim.setStartOffset(500);
    anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    myText.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

It's the very last line that's causing the exception - myText.startAnimation(anim).

Here's the error log

```
07-19 19:49:52.729  26036-26036/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.chrisbjohnson.colorbubbles/com.chrisbjohnson.colorbubbles.ActivityTitle}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1664)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1680)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:945)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3719)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:895)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.chrisbjohnson.colorbubbles.ActivityTitle.onCreate(ActivityTitle.java:44)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1628)
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Either a different way to handle it, or a way to fix what I'm doing.

Thanks.

Comment: Most probably, the problem is with `R.id.textViewStart`. It looks like its not defined in `activity_title_screen.xml`. That's why you are getting a `NullPointerException` on `myText.startAnimation(anim);`.

Comment: I think its a little more complex than that. When I first start the app that text view works fine. I only get a nullpointerexception when I unlock the phone again.

Comment: So I have one more piece of information that might be of help. It looks like the layout resource file is not being called correctly when onCreate is called in the title activity. I know this because any GUI element will cause the same nullpointerexception. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the time spent trying to figure this out, I realized I was just wasting my time. I fixed it by just making the lock screen not work in my app. Kind of a workaround, but the best thing I could find without wasting weeks of my life.